# Category tag pair show group parameter not working

Tags: safecracker, categories

I've got a safecracker form which edits a channel entry. I want to display the categories that have been selected for the entry through check boxes, I've used this code:

```
{categories show_group="13"}
   <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" id="{category_name}" value="{category_id}"{checked}> {category_name}<br>
{/categories}
```

Which works fine, the checkboxes that have been previously selected are showing up as selected, but it's ignoring the 'show_group="13"' parameter. It's showing all a categories for that channel but I just want it to show the category group 13.

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong? From the documentation it looks like I've got the right parameter, and 13 is definitely to category group id.

Is there any other way of displaying the categories selected for a certain category id for an entry?

Thanks,
Julie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A work-around is to use conditionals when displaying the categories, and set hidden form fields for any categories from other groups to preserve them when they're checked.

```
{categories}
  {if '{category_group_id}'=='13'}
    <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" id="{category_name}" value="{category_id}"{checked}> {category_name}<br>
  {/if}
  {if "{category_group_id}" != '13' && '{checked}' != ""}
    <input type="hidden" name="category[]" value="{category_id}"><br>
  {/if}
{/categories}
```

ps. you can use `{categories group_id="xx"}...{/categories}` to limit to a category group, but from my tests, that doesn't seem to preserve any categories  from other groups that might already have been selected.